# Hiding Title FIeld in Sharepoint not working

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am trying to do the following to hide the title field from the new and edit form but its still visible.

pls help

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Adds source list and content type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="currentWeb"></param>
        private void AddSourcesList(SPWeb currentWeb)
        {
            currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            #region Add Source content type.
            if(currentWeb.ContentTypes[SponsoringCommon.Constants.CONTENTTYPES_SOURCES_NAME] == null)
            {
                #region Hides title column
                    currentWeb.Lists.Add(SponsoringCommon.Constants.LISTNAMES_SOURCES_NAME, string.Empty, SPListTemplateType.GenericList);
                    SPList sourceList = currentWeb.Lists.TryGetList(SponsoringCommon.Constants.LISTNAMES_SOURCES_NAME);
                    SPField titleField = sourceList.Fields.GetField("Title");
                    titleField.Required = false;                    
                    titleField.ShowInEditForm = false;
                    titleField.ShowInDisplayForm = false;
                    titleField.ShowInNewForm = false;
                    titleField.Hidden = true;
                    titleField.Update(); 
                #endregion
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot see the rest of the code, but I had similar problem, and the thing I was missing is to `.Update()` the List and the Web. So in your case try to update *sourceList* and at the end *currentWeb*.

Hopefully, it will help solve your problem.

Comment: The problem is that I was adding the list, and trying to hide the title field, but further down the code there was also an SPContenttype being added to the list, apparently I had to hide the title field after adding the content type to the list.

Comment: Yeah i had to add field.update(); Updating the list.update() is not enough.